# Combining bytes into logical values

Tags: c#, byte

I'm getting back data in the (expected) following format:

```
\u0001\u0001\u0004\0\u0001\0\0\0
```

Each segment represents a byte. The first two segments `\u0001\u0001` represents the service version number, the second two `\u0004\0` represent the status code, and the final 4 `u0001\0\0\0` equals the request id.

How can I take the fields I KNOW go together and make a logical value out of the result? For example, the status code `\u0004\0` should be a signed-short and the request id should be an int.

What I've played around with, but I don't know the validity:

```
byte s1 = 0004;
byte s2 = 0;
short statusCode = (short)(s1 | (s2 << 8));

byte r1 = 0001;
byte r2 = 0;
byte r3 = 0;
byte r4 = 0;

int requestId = (int)(r1 | (r2 << 8) | (r3 << 16) | (r4 << 24));
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the issue? Are you trying to read that string in and convert it to the respective values?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Does your current setup work?

Comment: I don't know if my operations are logically sound. It's pretty easy to make a 4 and a 1 :s

Comment: You'd better go back to the basics and get this data into a byte[] intead of a string.  Although it is very unclear how you can have a string with both 2-byte and 1-byte values.  Much easier to tackle with MemoryStream and BinaryReader.

Comment: I am curious as to why you are doing this in C#. It's not like C# is known for its speed. Typically, when you are manipulating bits, it's for performance reasons (or you are interacting with a chip or IC).

Comment: @Dudemanword You don’t always have the control over what kind of data you receive. And just because you are decoding bytes, it doesn’t mean you are looking for speed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Dudemanword. I am able to read the result as a stream or byte array which is helpful. I just started as a string to visualize the response as I start my exploration.

Comment: Whoever is feeding you the data should probably be using \x for hexadecimal escapes and not \u which is intended for escaping Unicode characters. Where there's already a well established standard it makes sense to copy the pattern to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Dudemanword: I wouldn't say that is a typical use case for reading and writing bytes. Anyhow, C# is plenty fast at bitwise operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your logic seems fine, manual bit shifting can become quite tedious, especially when the amount of data you have to handle increases. It’s simple enough for 8 bytes, but for everything else, I would suggest you to look into marshalling bytes directly into objects.

For this, define a value type that explains your data:

```
public struct Data
{
    public short serviceVersion;
    public short statusCode;
    public int requestId;
}
```

Then, you can convert the string into a byte array, and marshall it as a `Data` object:

```
// raw input, as a string
string s = "\u0001\u0001\u0004\0\u0001\0\0\0";

// convert string into byte array
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

// interpret byte array as `Data` object
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
Data data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
handle.Free();

// access the data!
Console.WriteLine(data.serviceVersion); // 257
Console.WriteLine(data.statusCode); // 4
Console.WriteLine(data.requestId); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Exanding on @poke's post above; if you want to get really fancy you can do a `union` like effect

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct Data
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short serviceVersion;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public short statusCode;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int requestId;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong Value;
}
```

Where the use of the `Data.Value` field reads all of the bits you care about.

Additionally, using `unsafe` you can avoid the marshalling.

```
// raw input, as a string
string s = "\u0001\u0001\u0004\0\u0001\0\0\0";

// convert string into byte array
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
Data data = new Data();

unsafe
{
    Data* d = &data;

    fixed(byte* b = bytes)
    {
        *d = *((Data*)b);
    }
}
```